# Vanishing of cohomology groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, derham-cohomology

Given a smooth hypersurface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{2p+1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ of degree  $d \ge 5$ (with $p\ge 2$), when can we say that

$H^{p+1}(\mathcal{O}_X)=H^{p+1}(\Omega^1_X)=...=H^{p+1}(\Omega^{p-2}_X)=0$ ?

Are there some examples of such a hypersurface? Any suggestions on a possible direction of approaching this problem is more than welcome.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something basic but I think the weak Lefschetz theorem implies that these groups are always $0$ (for any $d>0$).

Comment: That can't be right: if $p=1$ and $d=4$, we are talking about a smooth quartic $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, for which $h^{p+1}(O_X)=h^{0,2}(X)=1$. 

Comment: @René Pannekoeck: sorry: to apply the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, the condition $p+1+i<2p$ must be satisfied for $i=0,\dots,p-2$. So if $p<2$, you have a problem. So what I am saying is true if $p>1$.

Comment: (note that the statement of the question is ambiguous if $p<2$)

Comment: @Rossler: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am sorry I forgot to specify but $p \ge 2$ in the question.